# Apache rewrite rule infinite loop for subpage

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, redirect, rewritecond

I am trying to redirect toast.allthesmarts.com to toast.allthesmarts.com/dayone

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} toast.allthesmarts.com
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ http://toast.allthesmarts.com/dayone/ [L,R,QSA]
```

But this gives me infinite loop. 
I tried this:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^toast.allthesmarts.com$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dayone$
    RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ http://toast.allthesmarts.com/dayone/ [L,R,QSA]
```

But it doesn't work ! 
I have done this many times, but my head is not working today ! Please help

note: there are other websites running via same apache

Comment: vote to close, really ? I would love to know why.

Comment: Where is this rule? In the config, or in a .htaccess file? Anyway, since you are rewriting everything to /dayone/ except for /dayone you do in deed get in a loop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change
'RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dayone$'

To
'RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dayone/$'

Comment: thanks that worked. It didn't load any assets though. SO I modified it like this: 'RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dayone(.*)$'